# How to add accessibility tags in jsPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf

How can we add tags for pdf text method. Previously I used server side PDF iTextSharp generator PDF where it has option to add tags.

`doc.text("<h1>Header Text</h1>",20,20)`